# Fastest way to write data into the database

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, sqlalchemy

My usecase is such..

I have a redshift cluster where i upload data into (Basically, i use pandas to just replace the data everyday).The frequency of the upload is every hour and the number of records are close to 35k.(They keep increasing everyday)

Now, i wanted to know the quickest way to write the data into the cluster.

1. Do i manually delete the existing data by using a delete query and then write data to redshift by using "dataframe.to_sql" ?
2. Do i just let the "dataframe.to_sql" function do the job automatically by adding "if_exists = replace" option?

Which is the quickest way to deal with data with huge number of records?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently [sqlalchemy-redshift](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sqlalchemy-redshift) uses psycopg2 so if you search for similar questions regarding PostgreSQL you should find some examples that might be helpful. For example, at the very least the `method="multi"` option of pandas' `to_sql` method might help speed up the upload.

As for deleting the data vs. dropping and re-creating the table via `if_exists="replace"`, the former will likely be faster, especially if you can [TRUNCATE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-truncate.html) the table instead of just deleting all the rows.

Comment: Appreciate the response.
Thanks a lot